# nginx secure download module not working

Tags: php, nginx

I try to implement this module to protect file downloads against hotlinking and limit bandwidth stealing: [ngx_http_secure_link_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html)

I get a 403 error. I think the mistake is somewhere in the PHP code.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
location /downloads/ {
    secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
    secure_link_md5 "$secure_link_expires$uri$remote_addr secret";

    if ($secure_link = "") {
        return 403;
    }

    if ($secure_link = "0") {
        return 410;
    }
}
```

PHP

```
function base64url_encode($data) { 
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
} 

$file = '/downloads/file1.txt';
$expires = time() + 3600;

$md5 = base64url_encode(md5( $expires . $file . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "secret" ));

$download_link = "http://example.com/downloads/?md5=$md5&expires=$expires";
```

Comment: Your `$md5` in PHP does not match `secure_link_md5` in nginx, the former has a space.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps are wrong

1. You dont have to put this in a quotes. This is not PHP. Quotes are
   not required here.
2. There is a space between $remote_addr and secret.
       Either remove this space. Or add space in your PHP code.
3. In Nginx config use the parameters ($arg_expires) not
   $secure_link_expires
4. Change your download link to include filename from variable and a Advice please place your secret before all the parameters

**PHP**

```
$md5 = base64url_encode(md5( "secret" . $expires . $file . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ));
$download_link = "http://example.com".$file."?md5=".$md5."&expires=".$expires;
```

**nginx config**

```
location /downloads/ {
    secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
    secure_link_md5 secret$arg_expires$uri$remote_addr;

    if ($secure_link = "") {
        return 403;
    }

    if ($secure_link = "0") {
        return 410;
    }
}
```

Please see my question. I have a bigger issue in the module than this. This works for me in node js. I tested my code in PHP. I haven't tested yours. But I guess it will work ;)